# How to position custom mdframed theorem boxes side by side?

Tags: positioning, theorems, mdframed, wrapfigure

I have custom theorem boxes which, some of them, I want to be placed next to each other. I tried using `wrapfig`, `minipage`, `multicol` `subfig` and `tabular`, but got none of them to work. Please see code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=30pt

\usepackage{subcaption}%

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}%
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}%
\usepackage{wrapfig}%
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%

\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}%                % Name
  {0pt}%                                  % Space above
  {0pt}%                                  % Space below
  {\small}%                               % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bf}%                                  % Theorem head font
  {\;}%                                   % Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%                             % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline = Abstand nach rechts oder neue Zeile
  {}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{myStyle}%
\newtheorem*{myBox}{Title}%

\newmdenv[skipabove=1pt,
skipbelow=9pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
linecolor=white,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
innerrightmargin=10pt,
innertopmargin=10pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm
innerbottommargin=10pt,
nobreak=true]{grayBoxNoBorder}%


\newenvironment{myBoxLeft}{\wrapfigure{l}{.45\textwidth}\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}\endwrapfigure}%
\newenvironment{myBoxRight}{\wrapfigure{r}{.45\textwidth}\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}\endwrapfigure}%
\newenvironment{myBoxFull}{\wrapfigure{l}{\textwidth}\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}\endwrapfigure}%
\newenvironment{myBoxHalf}{\wrapfigure{l}{.5\textwidth}\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}\endwrapfigure}%

\begin{document}

% First try
\begin{myBoxLeft}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxLeft}
\begin{myBoxRight}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxRight}
\clearpage
% Second try
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{myBoxFull}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxFull}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{myBoxFull}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxFull}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage
% Third try
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{myBoxHalf}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxHalf}
\columnbreak
\begin{myBoxHalf}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxHalf}
\end{multicols}

% \clearpage
%% Fourth try
% \begin{figure}
% \centering
% \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
% \begin{myBoxFull}
% \lipsum[2]
% \end{myBoxFull}
% \end{subfigure}
% \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
% \begin{myBoxFull}
% \lipsum[2]
% \end{myBoxFull}
% \end{subfigure}
% \end{figure}
%% doesn't work because error due to figure inside subfigure

\clearpage
% Fifth try
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{myBoxFull}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxFull}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{myBoxFull}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myBoxFull}
\end{minipage}
\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What can I do to place them side by side?

Comment: You can't overlap two wrapfigures, and from what I can tell you shouldn't be using them at all.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Place theorems next to each other?  Theorems to the left of images, or images to the left of theorems?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am trying to put two theorems next to each other.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it to work with minipage. Please see second try in my MWE. minipages are contiguous. Either it doesn't help adding a `%` after first `\end{minipage}`. I also tried with `\hfill` and `[t]` top aligned, but the result keeps being one box beneath the other and not next to each other. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you forget the `wrapping` part, `mdframed` boxes are easily arranged side by side with `minipage`, `tabluar`, ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=30pt

\usepackage{subcaption}%

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}%
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}%
\usepackage{wrapfig}%
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%

\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}%                % Name
  {0pt}%                                  % Space above
  {0pt}%                                  % Space below
  {\small}%                               % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                                  % Theorem head font
  {\;}%                                   % Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%                             % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline = Abstand nach rechts oder neue Zeile
  {}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{myStyle}%
\newtheorem*{myBox}{Title}%

\newmdenv[skipabove=1pt,
skipbelow=9pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
linecolor=white,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
innerrightmargin=10pt,
innertopmargin=10pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm
innerbottommargin=10pt,
nobreak=true]{grayBoxNoBorder}%


\newenvironment{myNewBox}{\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}}%
%\newenvironment{myBoxRight}{\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}}%
%\newenvironment{myBoxFull}{\wrapfigure{l}{\textwidth}\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}\endwrapfigure}%
%\newenvironment{myBoxHalf}{\wrapfigure{l}{.5\textwidth}\begin{grayBoxNoBorder}\begin{myBox}}{\end{myBox}\end{grayBoxNoBorder}\endwrapfigure}%

\begin{document}

% First try
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
\begin{myNewBox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myNewBox}
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
\begin{myNewBox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myNewBox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{myNewBox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myNewBox}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{myNewBox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myNewBox}
\columnbreak
\begin{myNewBox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myNewBox}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]